# Compact connected Riemannian manifolds are Ahlfors regular metric space

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact connected $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold; let $(X,d)$ denote its associated metric (length) space.  A comment on the original formulation of this post mentioned that $(X,d)$ is [Ahlfors $n$-regular](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319955/origin-of-term-ahlfors-david-regular), meaning that: there exist constants $L,U>0$ for which
$$
L  r^n\leq \mu(B(x,r))\leq U r^n$$
where $\mu$ is the $n$-dimensional Hausdorff measure and $B(x,r)$ denotes the ball in $(X,d)$ about $x\in X$ of radius $r>0$
*(i.e. each $\mu(B(x,r))\in \Theta( r^n)$)*.

1. Where can I find a proof or reference for this fact?
2. Can the constants $L,U$ be stated using the curvature and dimension of $(M,g)$?

Comment: Non-negative Ricci curvature implies the weaker doubling condition (see https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/lecture-19-volume-doubling-property/ ) but not Ahlfors regularity. For example, an infinite cylinder is not Ahlfors regular.

Comment: Ah, so are there examples of Ahlfors-Regular Riemannian manifolds (besides Euclidean space)?

Comment: The issue with the flat cylinder is that, for large $r$, a ball of radius $r$ is essentially a subcylinder length 2r, whose volume grows linearly with $r$.

Comment: There is no such issue when $M$ is compact (in the definition that I have seen of Ahlfors regularity, r is taken to be less than the diameter), and indeed every compact Riemannian manifold will be Ahlfors regular.

Comment: Oh really?  Can I find this recorded somewhere.  That would be perfect!  (Just need to quote it for motivation of my use of the condition in a working paper, and would like to read more for personal growth).

Comment: Regarding 1. Doesn't the Hausdorff measure equal volume in this case? Then if $r$ tends to $0$, the answer should follow from the fact that Riemannian manifolds are infinitesimly Euclidean, and the fact that when you divide (1) by $r^d$ the expression in the middle is continuous in $r$, and hence is bounded on any compact set. This argument should also tell you something about 2. For example, under a lower Ricci bound a diameter bound gives volume bound by Bishop-Gromov.

Comment: Actually, the claim seems false as stated: $M$ is compact, so it has a volume $V$ which is an upper bound for $\mu(B(x,r))$, and therefore there is no lower limit $L$ which will work for arbitrarily large $r$.

Comment: For $0\le r\le D=diam(M)$, you can just take $L$ and $U$ as the min and max of the continuous function $$f(x,r)=\begin{cases}\frac1r \mu(B(x,r))^{1/n}\ \text{ if }\ r>0\\ \frac\pi2 \Gamma(\frac n2+1)^{-1/n}\ \text{ if }\ r=0\end{cases}$$ over the compact region $M\times[0,D]$, where the second case corresponds to the Euclidean volume.

Comment: @MattF. Why do we distinguish the Euclidean case where?

Comment: @MattF. Also how can we guarantee that $\min_{x,r}\, f(x,r)\neq 0$?  I.e.: $L>0$.

Comment: @BLBA. The reason to distinguish the case $r=0$ is that the formula for $r>0$ is not defined for that case. Also it is a theorem that a continuous function with positive values at every point of a compact region has a positive minimum; you just have to prove the continuity by writing $\mu(B(x,r))$ as an integral over the tangent vectors at $x$ which correspond to geodesics between $x$ and points of the ball.

Comment: Oh really!?  This I didn't know.  Do you have a reference to this theorem?  This would be enough for me to complete the reference I need :)